# HTTP Error: cURL ERROR: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection nusoap in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, nusoap

I am try to fetch from soap webservice which's url is like  https://something.com/webservice.asmx
I tried by setting value of CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 3 and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE but it didn't worked.

Php version : 5.5.12
Apache : 2.4.9 using wamp server 2
I tried to access https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx 
and my code is working for this webservice but not for another webservice
my code looks like this

`$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl);
$client->soap_defencoding = 'utf-8';
$mysoapmsg ='somexml';
$response = $client->send($mysoapmsg, $soapaction);`

Comment: If the exact same code works for one web service but not another we won't be able to help much unless you give us more information about the other web service itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put in the details about the other web service; this is very vague. A normal web service call should look like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://domain.com/wservices.asmx?wsdl", array('login'          => "USERNAME",
                                                                        'password'       => "PASSWORD"));
$param = array("param_name" => $param_value);
$response = $client->__call("MethodName", array("parameters" => $param));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($response);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: you might need to upgrade cURL and php version, there could be a bug @ref: http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/07azn3bj39/43158-new-ssl-verify-result-0

Comment: I used soapclient instead of nusoap_client and it worked but i called method __dorequest() intead of __call. Thanks